# Error Logging in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-logging

My team has recently switched to rails, and we're yet to implement an error logging solution for our project.

I'd like something like Elmah - http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ - where the errors and details are logged and easily accessible.

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use and like [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/) (disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with them in any way). Another popular service in the Rails world for doing the same thing is [Exceptional](http://www.getexceptional.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search for a gem on `Rails log analyzing` and came across this awesome looking project called `request-log-analyzer` lead by `wvanbergen`. You can find the project on github: http://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer.

Also, take a look at some sample output: http://wiki.github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer/sample-output

This would be a very simple and effective way of tracking request-related errors, obviously.

For non-request-related errors that you'd like to log, I'd recommend just using the built-in [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/) and seeing if either 1) `request-log-analyzer` can interface with a `non-request` log file or if 2) you can play with the `request-log-analyzer` to also parse and display your own error log file in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks, this would also be helpful for stats purposes!